# (Reflection) Implicit and explicit lambda declaration

Tags: lambda, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I am trying to understand the reflection. I have the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array) {
println(lengthL1())
println(lengthL2(s))
println(lengthL1.get()) // Error
println(lengthL2.get(s)) // Error

println(lengthNL1.get())
println(lengthNL2.get(s))
println(lengthNL1())
println(lengthNL2(s))
}

val s = “1234”

val lengthL1: () -> Int = s::length
val lengthL2: (String) -> Int = String::length

val lengthNL1 = s::length
val lengthNL2 = String::length
```

Why I cannot call the `get` (See Error comments) when I declare the lambda?
Is there any difference between `lengthL1` and `lenghtNL1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s::length` is a property reference, which is an object of type [KProperty1](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/index.html). The `get` method is defined as [a member of this type](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/get.html).

If you declare a variable of a lambda type and initialize it with a property reference, you get a regular lambda (`KFunction1`). The `KFunction1` interface declares only the `invoke()` method, allowing you to call it as `lengthL1()`, but it does not declare any additional methods such as `get`.

Comment: I didn't expect that big change by only declaring the lambda type! Declaring types or not I thought that it would have no effect!

Comment: Well, if you declare `val x: Any = "abc"`, you also won't be able to access `x.length`, so I don't see why exactly this is surprising...

Comment: I am changing the type! That never crossed my mind! Feeling embarrassed!